# proof involving pre-measure, measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding the uniqueness of the Measure of an Outer-measure which is induced by a pre-measure.

My question is regarding the proof of the uniqueness of the Measure.

It is on Page 35 in this pdf:
http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~estep/assets/chapter5.pdf

Basically I don't understand the very last line of the proof where it says:

$\mu(A) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A \cap A_i) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v(A \cap A_i) = v(A)$

where $A$ is a set in $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) $, and $A_i$ is some disjoint sets in an Algebra called $\mathscr{A}$. Because the measure $\mu$ and $v$ is equal on the algebra $\mathscr{A}$, this I know. But I am not sure what properties was used here to arrive at $\mu(A) = v(A)$ in the above here.

My question is how do I know $\mu(A\cap A_i)$ =$v(A\cap A_i)$ where $A$ is a set in $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ ,$A_i$ is a set in $\mathscr{A}$. Because I know that $\mu$ and $v$ are equal for the sets in $\mathscr{A}$, but I am not sure if they are also equal for sets like $A\cap A_i$.

Could someone give some hints or comments.

Also my other question from the proof is, it seems from the first 2/3 of the proof, it shows $v \leq \mu$ and $\mu \leq v$ already (i.e. those lines before "Finally" paragraph). What is the purpose of the paragraph that starts with "Finally"? Because I thought the proof was done already before paragraph that started with "Finally". Is it just another way of proving the theorem? so the paragraph that starts with "Finally" is another proof of the same theorem?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, could someone give me some hints or comments on the above question?